# scollTo + hashchange: Weird back/forward behavior

Tags: jquery, hash, scrollto, hashchange

I'm trying to use Ariel Fiesler's scrollTo plugin in conjunction with Ben Alman's hashchange plugin. Basically I'm scrolling to different DIVs on my page, and trying to use hashchange for back/forward button functionality.

It sort of works, but it's inconsistent. On every other back or forward, it scrolls. But on the others it just jumps to the scroll position. So you get something like: 1. Jump, 2. Scroll, 3. Jump, 4. Scroll and so on.

Here's a link to the live site: http://www.6by7.net/

And the plugins I'm using:
http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html 
http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery LocalScroll + hashchange event browser compatibility issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5184876/jquery-localscroll-hashchange-event-browser-compatibility-issue)